# SQL: Conversion failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
SELECT
    *
    ,CASE
        WHEN emp_type='a' then '30'
        when emp_type='b' then '20'
        else '25' end as s
    , case when tbl_cut.dir_date='0' or tbl_cut.nameOFmonthe_cut='2018/05' then (coalesce(work_days_cut,0)-coalesce(count(addCut_id),0))
    else  (coalesce(s,0)-coalesce(count(addCut_id),0) end as 'days'
    , case when tbl_cut.dir_date='0' or tbl_cut.nameOFmonthe_cut='2018/05' then (((coalesce(work_days_cut,0)-coalesce(count(addCut_id),0)))*(coalesce([emp_price],0)))
    else (((coalesce((cast('s'as int)),0)-coalesce(count(addCut_id),0)))*(coalesce([emp_price],0))) end as 'salary'
FROM
(
    select distinct (emp_id)
    from
    (
        select emp_id  from tbl_employee
        union select emp_id from tbl_add_cut
        union select emp_id from tbl_cut
    ) tmp
) emp_ids

left join tbl_add_cut 
    on tbl_add_cut.emp_id=emp_ids.emp_id 
    and nameOFmonthe='2018/05'
left join tbl_cut 
    on tbl_cut.emp_id=emp_ids.emp_id
left join tbl_employee 
    on tbl_employee.emp_id=emp_ids.emp_id
inner join tbl_department
    on tbl_employee.depart_id=tbl_department.depart_id

--where emp_name like '%'+ @emp_name + '%' and [emp_type]=@emp_type
group by 
    tbl_employee.emp_id,tbl_employee.emp_name,tbl_department.depart_Des,[emp_degree], 
    tbl_employee.[emp_price],[emp_type],tbl_add_cut.nameOFmonthe, work_days_cut,
    tbl_cut.nameOFmonthe_cut,tbl_cut.dir_date,emp_work_days
```

I get this error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 's' to data type int.

Thanks

Comment: How would you logically convert varchar with a non-numeric representation to int? I think your problem is in the question. :-)

Comment: ( CASE
        WHEN emp_type='a' then '30'
        when emp_type='b' then '20'
        else '25' end as s) how can i use (s) with other columns

Comment: Which dbms?????

Comment: `coalesce((cast('s'as int)),0)` - this will literally never work. You may be able to get away with simply stripping out the single quotes that it's wrapped in....

Comment: On second thought, that probably won't work.  You'll need to rewrite the condition within your query, more likely than not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I see it. You're creating a salary field called 's', but you can't reference it yet because it's in the same query. Just use the same CASE statement for 's' in the 2nd CASE statement where you're referencing it. Here I removed the CAST in the 2nd use because you want it as an integer, not a string (removed the CAST, removed the single quotes around the numbers):

```
, CASE
    WHEN emp_type='a' then '30'
    when emp_type='b' then '20'
    else '25' end as s
, case when tbl_cut.dir_date='0' or tbl_cut.nameOFmonthe_cut='2018/05' then (coalesce(work_days_cut,0)-coalesce(count(addCut_id),0))
else  (coalesce(s,0)-coalesce(count(addCut_id),0) END as 'days'
, case when tbl_cut.dir_date='0' or tbl_cut.nameOFmonthe_cut='2018/05' then (((coalesce(work_days_cut,0)-coalesce(count(addCut_id),0)))*(coalesce([emp_price],0)))
else (((coalesce((CASE
    WHEN emp_type='a' then 30
    when emp_type='b' then 20
    else 25 end),0)-coalesce(count(addCut_id),0)))*(coalesce([emp_price],0))) end as 'salary'
```

Comment: thanks , i know that but i what i want to know is there some way to use 's'

Comment: i will use your way

Comment: Yeah, you really can't reference that derived column in the same query like that, sorry. What's weird is that you could use "ORDER BY [s]" at the bottom of the query and it would work fine.